# Create collection using metaplex js sdk

Tags: metaplex, nfts, metaplex-js, collection, sdk

I would like to create a collection and then add nft to it. The code I use:

```
 const a = (
    await metaplex
      .nfts()
      .create({
        name: "My off-chain name",
        uri: "https://arweave.net/y5e5DJsiwH0s_ayfMwYk-SnrZtVZzHLQDSTZ5dNRUHA",
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: 250,
        isCollection: true,
      })
      .run()
  ).nft;

  const { nft } = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .create({
      name: "My off-chain name",
      uri: "https://metadata.degods.com/g/9999.json",
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: 250,
      collection: findMetadataPda(a.mint.address),
    })
    .run();

  await metaplex.nfts().verifyCollection({
    mintAddress: nft.mint.address,
    collectionMintAddress: a.mint.address,
  });
```

the problem is that the above code snippet creates 2 separate nft but I would like the first nft to be the nft collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're experiencing is correct.

A collection points to parent/collection NFT that is created and referenced to.

Your entire collection should point to the collection NFT you created.

For more information about MCC collections on Solana you can check out the Metaplex site below :)

https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/certified-collections#collection-nfts

Comment: Oh thanks, i saw this site but idk why these tokens are not linked on https://explorer.solana.com/ (collection name do not appear on scanner)

Collection: BMvGhd5ng6PCun7qY9gYRw91VetgmMponKz8EsDdKhbJ
someNft: F7b2yg8KrAHFCNaFvoLjK8bUaZR4RVgzii5Xt8hy79c6

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to solve this? I think the new nft is not getting verified collection as part of the collection.

And the [docs](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/certified-collections#linking-regular-nfts-to-collection-nfts) also mention that there should be boolean property named Verified set to true. I could not figure out how to make it successful.